# Continue looping if address not found

Tags: r, lapply, ggmap

**AIM:** I am trying to retrieve a series of maps using the `get_map` function from `ggmaps`.

I know the following works when I use latitude and longitude:

```
houses_maps <- lapply(latlon,
                  function(x)
                    get_map(location = x,
                            zoom = 20, 
                            maptype = "satellite", 
                            source = "google"))
```

**PROBLEM:** It doesn't finish the loop when I use addresses instead of latitude and longitude. This is likely due to it not finding one of the addresses, for example with "tomet, 6-10, 25720 Bellver de Cerdanya, Lleida, Spain"

I get this error:

```
Error in data.frame(ll.lat = ll[1], ll.lon = ll[2], ur.lat = ur[1], ur.lon = ur[2]) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
In addition: Warning message:
geocode failed with status ZERO_RESULTS, location = "tomet, 6-10, 25720 Bellver de Cerdanya, Lleida, Spain" 
Called from: data.frame(ll.lat = ll[1], ll.lon = ll[2], ur.lat = ur[1], ur.lon = ur[2])
```

**QUESTION:** How can I get it to ignore the addresses it couldn't find and leave them NA and continue searching for the rest instead of stoping. I have 2,000 addresses and it's likely it wont find a few.

Comment: use `try` or `traCatch` to ignore or handle the error.

Comment: @RYoda could you give me a tryCatch example please?

Comment: `This is likely due to it not finding one of the addresses` Nope. Your Google Maps API key is most likely not enabled for geocoding. Try `geocode("tomet, 6-10, 25720 Bellver de Cerdanya, Lleida, Spain", output = "all")` to confirm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I neither have example data (please always provide data in your question) and
nor know many details of the `get_map` function I am demonstrating
just the basic idea here:

```
# simplified example data
latlon = c("address 1", "address 2", "address 3")

# mock the function
get_map <- function(location, ...) {
  if (location == "address 2") stop(paste("geocode failed with status ZERO_RESULTS, location =", location))
  return(location)
}


houses_maps <- lapply(latlon,
                      function(x)
                        tryCatch(get_map(location = x,
                                   zoom = 20, 
                                   maptype = "satellite", 
                                   source = "google"),
                                 error = function(e) {
                                   print(e)
                                   return(NA)
                                 }))
# <simpleError in get_map(location = x, zoom = 20, maptype = "satellite",
# source = "google"): geocode failed with status ZERO_RESULTS,
# location = address 2>    

houses_maps                      
# [[1]]
# [1] "address 1"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "address 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the try command to actually test the function beforehand. In your example it should be:

```
houses_maps <- lapply(latlon,
                  function(x)
                  res <- try(get_map(location = x,
                            zoom = 20, 
                            maptype = "satellite", 
                            source = "google"))
                  if(inherits(res, "try-error")) next
                  else{
                    get_map(location = x,
                            zoom = 20, 
                            maptype = "satellite", 
                            source = "google")}
                  )
```

I can't test this myself, so hope I closed all the parentheses but you get the gist of it.